# Javascript issue: Array of integers recieved as a string at the Web API controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Why i am getting a string in my web api controller when I am setting the  the property as

```
$("#ProfessionsCheckBoxes input:checked").each(function() { 
professionsChecked.push($(this).attr("Id")); 
}); 
$("#SelectedProfessions").val(professionsChecked);
```

SelectedProfessions is a list of string in my view model.
It is really frustrating Like if I check two check boxes,

I get in my controller "2,3" at the 0 index of the list i.e: `[0] = "2,3"`. Not not a list like: `[0] ="2"` and `[1] = "3"`

Note1: 
This is how I am generating my checkboxes:

```
<div id="ProfessionsCheckBoxes" class="some item">
            <div class="form-group thirds">
                @if (Model.Professions != null)
                {
                    foreach (var item in Model.Professions)
                    {
                        <div class="one-third">
                            @Html.Label(item.Name)
                            @Html.CheckBox(item.Name, item.IsChecked, new {id = item.Id})
                        </div>
                    }
                }
            </div>
        </div>
```

Note2: I am submit the form through an ajax call with form.serialize() method.

Comment: This is not the right way to post arrays, default model binder will not understand it. Check this http://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to put the values in a separate elements of your `<form>` with the same name instead of generate and array and then put the whole array content as a value of your element, If the element is an `<input type="hidden">` as you said in your comments you can use:

```
$("#ProfessionsCheckBoxes input:checked").each(function() { 
  $("form").append('<input type="hidden" name="SelectedProfessions" value="' + $(this).attr("Id") + '"></input>');
});
```

Hope this helps,

Comment: I don't have experience with asp mvc, what html type is your `SelectedProfessions` element? This info can help me to rewrite the answer to fit your requirement `:)`

Comment: its a hidden field in html.

Comment: it's and `<input type="hidden">`?

Comment: Yes it is, <input type="hidden">

Comment: I update my answer I hope now it's more accurate `:)`.

Comment: still getting it as a null., [0] = null.

Comment: Oh it worked, instead of appending to the field, i appended the field to the form. And its working now. Thanks.

Comment: @Obviously fantastic `:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try editing the name of your inputs in the HTML to something like:

```
<form method="get">
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Politics"/> Politics<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="Movies"/> Movies<br/>
    <input type="checkbox" name="options[]" value="World "/> World<br/>
    <input type="submit" value="Go!" />
</form>
```

Notice the array brackets after options.